# How to Use Baire's Theorem to Show a set is not Nowhere Dense?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence of closed, successively inclusive sets,in the complete metric space, R, the real numbers.  I wish to use Baire's Catagory Theorem (BCT) to show that at least one of them is not nowhere dense (nd) .
A corollary to BCT, I understand, states that a sequence of nd sets in R has an nd union. If the union were not nd, then at least one of the sequence of sets would not be nd.
So,  if I can show the closure of the union to have a non-empty interior, then one of the closed sets would not be nd, by the corollary.
I believe the union is closed, because the closed sets grow inclusively, but I have not shown this to be true.
Further, if I can show the union has a non-empty interior, then, with the corollary, job done!   Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the union of an increasing nest of closed sets is closed: consider the sets $\left[\frac1n,1\right]$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, for instance.

You also don’t want to look at the **closure** of the union. If $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an enumeration of the rationals, and we set $F_n=\{q_k\in\Bbb Q:k\le n\}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, then each $F_n$ is a nowhere dense closed set, but $\operatorname{cl}\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n=\Bbb R$, which certainly has non-empty interior. You need to look just at the union of your nest. In this example that union is $\Bbb Q$, which does indeed have empty interior, as ensured by the Baire category theorem.

If you can show that the union of your closed sets has non-empty interior, then you can indeed conclude that on of the closed sets has non-empty interior.

Comment: My thinking was jogged by your examples that led me successfully (I believe) to argue the individual sets that concerned me are closed.  I did not need to show that their union was closed.  I then applied the contra-positive of the corollary to BCT to solve exercise 10 of Chapter 1, Section 3 in Gamelin's and Greene's "Inro to Topology", 2nd ed.